# an error to find maximum index in array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to make an array 15*15 and fill them with these code and I want to find max of a row of it.
I wrote this codes in MATLAB to make an array:

```
a = zeros (15) - inf;

for i=1:15 
    k2=4;
    l2=1;

    k=floor((i-1)/3);
    l=mod((i-1),3);
    f=false;
    if (k==k2 && abs(l2-l)==1)
        f=true;
    end
    if(l==l2 && k2-k==1)
        f=true;
    end
    if(k2-k==1 && abs(l2-l)==1)
        f=true;
    end

    if (f)
        a(i,14)=100;
    end
end
max=200;
for i=1:15
    if(find(2,i) < max)
        max=i;
    end
end

max=0
```

when I wrote these codes to find maximum index in 2nd row of array this error shown:

> > b=a(2,:)

```
b =

     1  -Inf     1     1     1     1  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf

>> [~,index]=max(b)
??? Indexing cannot yield multiple results.
```

Comment: Isn't there something missing in the first line?

Comment: yes , after zeros ... I fill array (a) with -inf by 2 for loop.

Comment: BTW you can create a matrix of `-Inf` just by subtracting `inf` from the zeros matrix so you don't need the loops. I have edited your code to reflect this.

Comment: @Dan: what is your edit of the code good for? The line `zeros (15,15) - inf;` does not make sense at all when the created array is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: @H.Muster Yes you are correct. I did not notice that the original question just had zeros assigned to nothing. It should be a = zeros(15) - inf; based on the OPs comment above.

Comment: No, actually `a = -inf(15);` would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have variable max and trying to use function max.

It's a good practice to check for existing names with `exist var_name` or `which var_name` command.

Rename your variable `max` in the code and remove it from the workspace with `clear max`.

Comment: What to explain. You define variable in `max=200`. Then trying to call function max. In MATLAB variable indexing and function call have the same syntax. Function can produce multiple outputs, but indexing cannot.

Comment: Matlab doesn't know if you want to use the function max() or the variable you created called max. Basically just give your variable max a different name.

Comment: @Dan: yes, forgot to mention this.